# awk is removing tabs when it shouldnt

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the following file

```
#
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/ftp.log                         640  5    1000 *     J
/var/log/hwmond.log                      640  5    1000 *     J
/var/log/ipfw.log                        640  5    1000 *     J
/var/log/lpr.log                         640  5    1000 *     J
/var/log/ppp.log                         640  5    1000 *     J
/var/log/wtmp                            644  3    *    @01T05 B
```

I would like to change the column that is equivalent with count with a different number.

I have been able to do that with the following command.

```
cat /etc/newsyslog.conf | awk '$1~"\\/var*"{$3="3333a"}1'
```

However, the result of this command breaks all of the tabs in the file. and the file results in the following which is not ideal.

```
#
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/ftp.log 640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/hwmond.log 640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/ipfw.log 640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/lpr.log 640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/ppp.log 640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/wtmp 644 3333a * @01T05 B
```

**EDIT**

I was able to amend it a bit with the following, but its not perfect yet.

```
 awk '$1~"\\/var*"{{$1=$1"\t\t\t"}{$3="3333a"}}1' /etc/newsyslog.conf
```

which resulted in

```
#
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/ftp.log                         640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/hwmond.log                      640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/ipfw.log                        640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/lpr.log                         640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/ppp.log                         640 3333a 1000 * J
/var/log/wtmp                        644 3333a * @01T05 B
```

Comment: Don't use tabs if you want consistent formatting, because it is indeterminate where a particular terminal will take the carriage upon `\t`. I consider them obsolete for purposes of human readable text because of this inconsistency. There's always [expand](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) to get rid of tabs if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

For fixed-width data, usually safest to extract the substrings directly:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\/var/ {$0 = substr($0,1,45) "3333a" substr($0,51)} 1' file
```

```
#
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/ftp.log                         640 3333a 1000 *     J
/var/log/hwmond.log                      640 3333a 1000 *     J
/var/log/ipfw.log                        640 3333a 1000 *     J
/var/log/lpr.log                         640 3333a 1000 *     J
/var/log/ppp.log                         640 3333a 1000 *     J
/var/log/wtmp                            644 3333a *    @01T05 B
```

---

Ed makes a good point in his comment below. You might want one of:

```
expand file | awk '$1 ~ /^\/var/ {$0 = substr($0,1,45) "3333a" substr($0,51)} 1'
pr -te file | awk '$1 ~ /^\/var/ {$0 = substr($0,1,45) "3333a" substr($0,51)} 1'
```

Comment: all other solutions posted so far will break when some lines have the owner:group field populated but this one will break when some of the spaces between fields are tabs so idk.... the OP needs to tell us a bit more about his input files but I think this has the best chance of working and makes the most sense, just get rid of the tabs with pr -e -t or similar first.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1~"\\/var*\t\t"{$3="3333a"}1' /etc/newsyslog.conf
```

should do the trick. Note: it is always better to avoid multiple use of cat and awk.

Comment: Same result even when awk is applied to the file instead of the stdout of cat

Answer (score 0):

For keeping formatting intact prefer `sed` over `awk`:

```
sed -rn '\#^/var/#s/^(([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2})[^[:blank:]]+(.*)/\13333a\3/p' file
/var/log/ftp.log                         640  3333a    1000 *     J
/var/log/hwmond.log                      640  3333a    1000 *     J
/var/log/ipfw.log                        640  3333a    1000 *     J
/var/log/lpr.log                         640  3333a    1000 *     J
/var/log/ppp.log                         640  3333a    1000 *     J
/var/log/wtmp                            644  3333a    *    @01T05 B
```

On OSX use `sed -E` instead instead of `sed -r`.